# Get values from corresponding row CSV Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have multiple csv files like this:

csv1:

```
h1,h2,h3
aa,34,bd9
bb,459,jg0
```

csv2:

```
h1,h5,h2
aa,rg,87
aa,gru,90
bb,sf,459
```

For each value in column 0 with header h1, I'd like to get its corresponding h2 values from all the csv files in a folder. A sample output could be

```
csv1: (aa,34),(bb,459)
csv2: (aa,87,90),(bb,459)
```

I'm a little clueless on how to go about doing this.

PS- I don't want to use pandas.

PPS- I'm able to do it by hardcoding the value from column 0, but I don't want to do it that way since there are hundreds of rows.

This is a small piece of code I've tried. It prints the values of h2 for 'aa' in different lines. I want them to be printed in the same line.

```
import csv
with open("test1/sample.csv") as csvfile:
     reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile,  delimiter = ",")
     for row in reader:
         print(row['h1'], row['h2'])
```

Comment: have you looked at https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import glob
import csv
import os
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
path = "path_to_folder"
for fle in (glob.glob("*.csv")):
    with open(os.path.join(path,fle)) as f:
        header = next(f).rstrip().split(",")
        # if either does not appear in header the value will be None
        h1 = next((i for i, x in enumerate(header) if x == "h1"),None)
        h2 = next((i for i, x in enumerate(header) if x == "h2"),None)
        # make sure we have both columns before going further
        if h1 is not None and h2 is not None:
            r = csv.reader(f,delimiter=",")
            # save file name as key appending each h1 and h2 value
            for row in r:
                d[fle].append([row[h1],row[h2]])
print(d)

defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'csv1.csv': [['aa', '34'], ['bb', '459']], 'csv2.csv': [['aa', '87'], ['aa', '90'], ['bb', '459']]})
```

It is a quick draft, it presumes all files are delimited by `,` and all h1 and h2 columns have values, if so it will find all pairings keeping order.

To get a set of unique values we can use a set and set.update:

```
d = defaultdict(set) # change to set

for fle in (glob.glob("*.csv")):
    with open(os.path.join(path,fle)) as f:
        header = next(f).rstrip().split(",")
        h1 = next((i for i, x in enumerate(header) if x == "h1"),None)
        h2 = next((i for i, x in enumerate(header) if x == "h2"),None)
        if h1 is not None and h2 is not None:
            r = csv.reader(f,delimiter=",")
            for row in r:
                d[fle].update([row[h1],row[h2]) # set.update

print(d)
defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {'csv1.csv': {'459', '34', 'bb', 'aa'}, 'csv2.csv': {'459', '90', '87', 'bb', 'aa'}})
```

If you are sure you always have h1 and h2 you can reduce the code to simply:

```
d = defaultdict(set)
path = "path/"
for fle in (glob.glob("*.csv")):
    with open(os.path.join(path, fle)) as f:
        r = csv.reader(f,delimiter=",")
        header = next(r)
        h1 = header.index("h1")
        h2 = header.index("h2")
        for row in r:
            d[fle].update([row[h1], row[h2]])
```

lastly if you want to keep the order the elements are found we cannot use a set as they are unordered so we would need to check if either element was already in the list:

```
for fle in (glob.glob("*.csv")):
    with open(os.path.join(path, fle)) as f:
        r = csv.reader(f,delimiter=",")
        header = next(r)
        h1 = header.index("h1")
        h2 = header.index("h2")
        for row in r:
            h_1, h_2 = row[h1], row[h2]
            if h_1 not in d[fle]:
                d[fle].append(h_1)
            if h_2 not in d[fle]:
                d[fle].append(h_2)
print(d)
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'csv2.csv': ['aa', '87', '90', 'bb', '459'], 'csv1.csv': ['aa', '34', 'bb', '459']})
```

Comment: But is there a way I can merge `['aa', '87'], ['aa', '90']` into `['aa', '87', '90']`?

Comment: @dan, no worries, I threw it together pretty quick so no doubt can be optimised.

Comment: @dan yes indeed we can use extend or uses sets I will edit after I grab some dinner

Comment: Sure. I'm sorry if I stopped you. Thank you.

Comment: No prob, if you are sure there are always going to be h1 and h2's you can use index to get the column index for each and remove the if check